# Get Aurora IP and use it in UserData for another instance in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I have a CloudFormation script which creates 2 instances - an Aurora RDS server and an EC2 instance which will use it. I need to use the Aurora's IP address in my init script for the EC2 instance so I can seed the database.

So Aurora needs to be up and running before my init script on the EC2 executes. The other thing is I need the IP address.

```
"UserData"         : {
    "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : [
            "",
            [
                "<script>\n",
                "seedtool.exe ", { "Ref" : "MyAuroraDbInstance::InternalIP" }, "\n",
                "</script>\n"
            ]
        ]
    }
},
```

So my question is, what do I put instead of `MyAuroraDbInstance::InternalIP` in the above script?

Comment: You should never try to use an IP address directly for an RDS instance/cluster. For Aurora you should be using the read/write cluster endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Fn::GetAtt on the DBInstance and request an attribute of Endpoint.Address.  This will not give an IP, it will give a CNAME

Comment: To add to this answer, do not use the IP address directly. Instead, use the CNAME that `Fn::GetAtt` gives you.